# backbone.js collection view example using marionette template

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone.js-collections

Can you please suggest me some example for showing list view through marionette template system. Basically, I have a marionette template and based on the template i am creating a table list.

Comment: Did you mean Backbone templating system? Marionette does not implement any specific template handler. Backbone comes packaged with Underscore's _.template() by default.

Comment: Stackoverflow is around to help you resolve problems with your implementation, not design. I think your question will be better served at http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 38):

To create a list of table rows with Backbone Marionette you'll need to define five things:

- A model for each row
- A collection to hold all the row models
- A `CollectionView` to iterate through the collection
- An `ItemView` to provide row-specific functionality
- A template for the `ItemView` that provides the markup for each row

## Sample Use Case

Say you have the following data:

```
var stooges = [{ name: 'moe', age: 44, userid: 1}, 
               { name: 'larry', age: 44, userid: 2}, 
               { name: 'curly', age: 44, userid: 3}];
```

### Define a model and collection

For the following data you'd want to have a model:

```
var StoogeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

where you can set up some sensible defaults for your data and other properties, like `idAttribute`. There are plenty of references on how to customize your model. Your collection should, at minimum, take the `stoogeModel`.

```
var StoogeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: StoogeModel
});
```

### Set up your views

To iterate and render your collection into a table, all you'll need is a `CollectionView` and an `ItemView`.

```
var StoogesCollectionView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  tagName: "table",
  childView: StoogeItemView
});
```

All `CollectionViews` need at minimum a `childView` which is an `ItemView` (which we define below) that they will use to derive the functionality to create the html for each row, and a `collection` which is the collection holding the models that populate each row. We'll pass this collection in when we instatiate a`stoogesCollectionView`. The `tagName` property tells Backbone to encapsulate the children in a `table` tag.

```
var StoogeItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  tagName: "tr",
  template: '#stooge-template'
});

<script type="text/template" id="stooge-template">
  <td id="name"><%= name %></td>
  <td id="age"><%= age%></td>
  <td id="userid"><%= userid%></td>
</script>
```

All `ItemViews` require a template which we define in our HTML document, here it's `#stooge-template`. If the `ItemView` is a child of a collection you don't have to define its model, it will be provided by the parent `CollectionView`. The HTML rendered by each child `StoogeItemView` will be encapsulated by `tr` tags, because what we want is a row for each child of the collection view.

From the `ItemView` you can handle events at the "row" level, like `click` or `focus` on a row column. You can also handle changes to the model that was passed in. Additionally, from the `ItemView` you could decide to pass in helpers that can manipulate the way data is displayed in its template.

### Putting it all together

Now we have defined our model, collection, collection view, child item view, and the item view template. Next, we'll connect all these pieces.

#### Populate your collection

You pass in the array of stooges to the constructor of your collection.

```
var myStooges = new StoogeCollection(stooges);
```

These are shaped into models, and they load your collection.

#### Rev up your `CollectionView`

You pass your loaded collection to your collection view.

```
var myStoogesView = new StoogesCollectionView({ collection: myStooges  });
```

#### Render your view

All Marionette views come packaged with a `render` method. In our case, invoking

```
myStoogesView.render();
```

will create a `<table>` with three `<tr>` elements each with a column each for the `name`, `age`, and `userid` fields in our dataset. To insert the resulting HTML in the DOM we simply use the view's `el` property. For simplicty, we can inject the view straight into the body

```
document.body.appendChild(myStoogesView.el);
```

or using jQuery:

```
$(document.body).append(myStoogesView.el);
```

## Beyond this example

There is *much* functionality that we didn't even begin to discuss. Read the [docs](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/tree/master/docs)! And check out the many many tutorials. Hope this brief intro helps!

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I have a question. I have a Json like this { 'status' => 'Success', data : [ { 'set1': 'set2', 'set3':'set4' }] } . How do I set the 'status' value in the collection template ? since collection template only hold 'data' array . Should I use two different views for that ?

Comment: I don't mind answering your last question, but StackOverflow prefers that you open up a new post for questions not directly related to the original post.

Comment: Why the documentation is never as simple as that? Thank you!

Comment: Beautiful answer, @seebiscuit

Comment: @seebiscuit so did user opened new question ?