# Error : CollectionView require ItemView

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

My example :

```
var stooges = [{ name: 'moe', age: 44, userid: 1}, 
               { name: 'larry', age: 44, userid: 2}, 
               { name: 'curly', age: 44, userid: 3}];





var StoogeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});


var StoogeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: StoogeModel
});



var StoogeItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  tagName: "tr",
  template: '#stooge-template'
});

var StoogesCollectionView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  tagName: "table",
  childView: StoogeItemView
});






var myStooges = new StoogeCollection(stooges);

var myStoogesView = new StoogesCollectionView({ collection: myStooges  });


myStoogesView.render();

document.body.appendChild(myStoogesView.el);
```

This example I read in topic [backbone.js collection view example using marionette template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673371/backbone-js-collection-view-example-using-marionette-template)  but I have error:

**marionette_backbone.js:1299 Uncaught NoItemViewError: An `itemView` must be specified**

Help me please.

Comment: Which version of marionette are you using?

Comment: I am not sure, but it could be because of some version mismatch, I copy pasted your code in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cyclone/f70z64ef/1/), added libraries and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Marionette 1.x as a dependency in your project, but you're attempting to use 2.x interfaces.  [In 1.x `CollectionView`s used an "`itemView`"](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v1.8.8/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-itemview), while [2.x changed the naming to "`childView`"](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.0.0/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-childview)

Changing your `StoogesCollectionView` definition to use the `itemView` naming should fix your issue:

```
var StoogesCollectionView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  tagName: "table",
  itemView: StoogeItemView
});
```

Alternatively, you can upgrade Marionette to a newer version.